# Safe refactorings when migrating from Java 6 to Java 7

Tags: java, java-7, java-6

What are safe refactorings when migrating an application from Java 6 to Java 7?

For example one can consider using the new diamond operator, the new automatic resource management a.k.a. try with resources, multi-catch functionality but are there any more?

Answer (score 1):

Diamond operator / type inference is safe.

try-with-resources is mostly safe. If you didn't close some of your files, streams properly before, it will also correct a few bugs for free. But this may have side effects.

Multi-catch has the same caveats, if you replace `catch (Exception)` or worse: `catch (Throwable)` by proper multi-catching, you could have some throwables bubbling up the stack that got caught before (`NullPointerException`s and the like mostly).